# What is the difference between t_ignore, pass and t.lexer.skip() in ply.lex?

Tags: python, lex, lexer, ply

All three can be used to skip, ignore or pass over the characters. For example:

```
def t_error(t):
  pass

def t_error(t):
  t.lexer.skip()

def t_default(t): # put at the extreme end and assuming there are no string definitions
  r'.'
  pass or skip()
```

So all three seem to serve the same purpose in this case. I admit there is more elegancy in some methods than others.

What are the real differences between `pass`, `t_ignore` and `t.lexer.skip()`?

Answer (score 0):

All these functions are described in the [PLY documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html).

`t.lexer.skip()` is mainly used in a error situation to advance the input a fixed number of characters without processing the characters.

`t_ignore` and `pass` can both be used in a similar fashion. `t_ignore` is a special rule that is used to ignore characters that play no part in the recognition. It is mainly intended to be used for ignoring whitespace and similar types of characters. It can be used to ignore comments, for example, but the manual gives a warning against doing that in case it causes problems with other recognition functions. For example a comment can be ignored by:

```
t_ignore_COMMENT = r'\#.*'
```

`pass`is used to discard a lexeme without generating a token, once it has been recognised. The manual gives a similar example for the comment:

```
def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'\#.*'
    pass
    # No return value. Token discarded
```